# How to debug React-Native (Expo) app apk bugs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there any method to catch errors and bugs in built apk?
I tries to build with expo:build and also with EAS. In first one on some screens it freezes. In EAS build app just shutting down.
In dev mode app just works fine.

Answer (score 2):

1)You can use an automated error logging system like [Sentry](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/) to track errors at production. If your app uses an EAS build, you can use native crash reporting in addition to tracking javascript errors with the Sentry. But if your app uses the classic build system you can track only javascript errors with the sentry.

2)If your Android app is on Google Play, you can look at the crashes section of the Google Play Console.

3)You can connect your Android device which installed apk to your computer and run adb logcat to view the logs.

4)You can use also logcat with the Android Studio to look at the error logs of your app.

[image]

More info: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/debugging/